# Strange behaviour on last line in terminal using Tmux in SSH session

Tags: command-line, ssh, tmux

I am connecting to an Ubuntu 16.4 server over SSH. On the remote computer, I am using Tmux. On the local machine, I am on Windows 10. 
This behaviour is the same no matter if I am using Cygwin or Linux Subsystem on windows.
Whenever the terminal inside of tmux, the last line of the terminal acts crazy. It is like whenever the terminal is at the bottom using <kbd>arrow-up</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to retrieve previously run commands works, but editing those commands does not. It is like insert has been pushed down.
[small gif showing the behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7j77.gif)

What can I do about it? I am going crazy....

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to TMUX.